# receive json data from api

Tags: json, javascript-objects

I have an api service that sends a json data to my page via post, from my page I have to extract them and return a json file.
In php language I can open data with this code:

```
<?php
     header('Content-Type: application/json');
     header('Allow: POST'); 
     $a = array();
     $a = file_get_contents('php://input');
     echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

the problem is that I would like to have the same result in javascript and then integrate the data in an asp page. do you think it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. If you do not use any FE framework I would recommend to use jQuery AJAX to call your endpoint. For basic usage it will be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/api/endpoint',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            // Data you want to send along with POST body
            data: {
                content: 'something'
            },
            success: function (response) {
                // what to do with response
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                // What to do on error
                console.log(error.message);
            }
        });
```

There are a lot more how to work with AJAX (headers, use of promises, etc..). Also do not forget to import jQuery and AJAX libraries on your web in `<head></head>` to be able to use them.